# g++ fatal error: cannot open file '/usr/local/include/iostream': Permission denied

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I'm new to C++ programming and I'm trying to setup my development environment.The goal is to compile and run the following basic "hello world" program:

```
#include<iostream>


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

When I try to compile this using g++, clang, clang++ or cpp I always get the following error:

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/clang -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g /Users/robinvanderschuren/dev/c++/hello-world.cpp -o /Users/robinvanderschuren/dev/c++/hello-world
/Users/robinvanderschuren/dev/c++/hello-world.cpp:1:9: fatal error: cannot open file '/usr/local/include/iostream': Permission denied
#include<iostream>
        ^
1 error generated.

Build finished with error(s).
```

I have installed xcode-select via `xcode-select --install`. When I try to run the same build command using sudo it works as expected. Is there a way to fix this or should I adjust the build command to run as sudo?

The full verbose output is:

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /Users/robinvanderschuren/dev/c++/hello-world.cpp -o /Users/robinvanderschuren/dev/c++/hello-world --verbose
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple arm64-apple-macosx12.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name hello-world.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=non-leaf -fno-strict-return -fno-rounding-math -funwind-tables=2 -fobjc-msgsend-selector-stubs -target-sdk-version=13.1 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu apple-m1 -target-feature +v8.5a -target-feature +fp-armv8 -target-feature +neon -target-feature +crc -target-feature +crypto -target-feature +dotprod -target-feature +fp16fml -target-feature +ras -target-feature +lse -target-feature +rdm -target-feature +rcpc -target-feature +zcm -target-feature +zcz -target-feature +fullfp16 -target-feature +sm4 -target-feature +sha3 -target-feature +sha2 -target-feature +aes -target-abi darwinpcs -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -debug-info-kind=standalone -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 820.1 -v -resource-dir /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -Wno-reserved-identifier -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-bitwise-instead-of-logical -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/Users/robinvanderschuren/dev/c++ -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-cxx-modules -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fcommon -fcolor-diagnostics -clang-vendor-feature=+messageToSelfInClassMethodIdReturnType -clang-vendor-feature=+disableInferNewAvailabilityFromInit -clang-vendor-feature=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -fno-odr-hash-protocols -clang-vendor-feature=+enableAggressiveVLAFolding -clang-vendor-feature=+revert09abecef7bbf -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoAlignAttr -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoNullAttr -mllvm -disable-aligned-alloc-awareness=1 -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /var/folders/_k/wnk1hjmj5s7c59y8lssj5d600000gn/T/hello-world-644262.o -x c++ /Users/robinvanderschuren/dev/c++/hello-world.cpp
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202) default target arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
/Users/robinvanderschuren/dev/c++/hello-world.cpp:1:9: fatal error: cannot open file '/usr/local/include/iostream': Permission denied
#include<iostream>
        ^
1 error generated.

Build finished with error(s).
```

So in summary: I try to compile a basic helloworld.cpp file to be able to run it and I expect it to compile without needing sudo.

Comment: What are the permissions on `/usr/local/include/iostream`?

Comment: Weirdly enough when I do `ls -l -a` in `/usr/local/include` I only see this: 
`drwxr-x---  14 root  wheel  448 Jul 14  2022 protobuf`

Comment: Assuming you're neither the user `root` nor in the `wheel` group, that output says that you don't have read permissions on that file. Also, you should add the info to your question with an [edit] (comments are transient)

Comment: I ran `sudo su` before I did the `ls -l -a` so I assume I'm the user `root` right?

Comment: How `ls` was run is irrelevant. What matters is what user/group `clang` is running under.

Comment: How can I adjust g++ or another of these compilers to have the correct privileges?

Comment: IMO you should uninstall Xcode and install it again.

Comment: Already uninstalled Xcode and xcode-select and re-installed only xcode-select

Comment: where did `/usr/local/include/iostream` come from? The system include files would normally be elsewhere

Comment: Looking at the verbose output (see above) it is included for some reason in the search tree for the iostream library.

Comment: I resolved it by doing `chmod 2775 /usr/local/include`